# Como transformar uma imagem retangular em um círculo (sem distorcê-la)

Tags: html, css

Conforme mostrado na imagem abaixo, eu consigo fazer a figura **retangular** ficar redonda, porém ela fica distorcida:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.posts .posts-item img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  background-position: center center;
}
.posts.round .round-container img {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
figure img {
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 12rem;
  height: 12rem;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="posts-item">
  <div class="title">Conheça a lista dos melhores cafés</div>
  <figure>
    <div class="round-container"><img src="http://vidafit.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/cafe-coracao-776x517.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, onsectetur dispiscing</figcaption>
  </figure>
</a>
```

Alguém sabe como resolver isso pra qualquer imagem que eu colocar?

Comment: Veja se te ajuda: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jrBqAp

Comment: Seria tipo isso, mas a imagem teria que ser de um tamanho específico e pra mim não serve ainda (como essa é grande, ficou aparecendo só a colher no círculo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloquei a imagem dentro de um container, adicionando um tamanho fixo e o `border-radius`. Depois, ajustei a própria imagem dentro desse container com o `transform`.

```css
.round-container {
    width: 17rem;
    height: 17rem;
    align-self: center;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin: 2.3rem auto 2.5rem auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.round-container img {
    width: initial;
    height: inherit;
    max-width: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<h1><span>ice dream</span></h1>

<figure>
  <div class="round-container">
  <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/bdf78d98740c3a8962814afcaa5ea1c6/3zeuwsd/PnYmw7l78/tumblr_static_icecream.jpg">
  </div>
  <figcaption>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, onsectetur dispiscing
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

O mesmo código no [codepen](http://codepen.io/biibis/pen/KgqdyL).

Comment: Maiz Obrigado pelo codigo, deu certi :). Mas eu não consigo deixar a imagem responsiva e precisava, voce saberia como? Obrigado

Comment: Bom, pra mim a imagem já está "responsiva" haha Como seria exatamente responsiva pra você?

Comment: obrigado pela resposta! Seria em acompanhar o tamanho da tela, pc, celular, tablete, ela se encaixar a 100% em todas os dispositivos. tentei trocar widht e height por % mas nao deu certo!

Answer (score 3):

Há várias formas de fazer, como praticamente tudo que envolve html e css.

O problema no seu caso é que sua imagem não possui o mesmo valor de altura e largura, mas você força que ela tenha ao definir as propriedades `height` e `width`. Consequentemente a imagem ficará "esticada". Três possíveis soluções são:

- editar a imagem, de modo que a altura e a largura tenham o mesmo valor.
- criar um elemento *wrapper* contendo as propriedades que dão forma ao elemento (altura, largura, borda) e fazer com o que o elemento interno (uma imagem) tenha 100% da altura do elemento pai.

  ```css
  .img-wrapper {
    height: 12rem;
    width : 12rem;
    
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden
  }

  .img-wrapper > img {
    height: 100%
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class='img-wrapper'>
    <img src='http://vidafit.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/cafe-coracao-776x517.jpg'>
  </div>
  ```
- definir a url da imagem na propriedade `background` e usar [`background-size: cover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) para fazer com que a imagem de fundo "cubra" todo o espaço do elemento.

  ```css
  .image {
    height: 12rem;
    width : 12rem;
    
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-image: url(http://vidafit.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/cafe-coracao-776x517.jpg);
    background-size: cover
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class='image'></div>
  ```

Comment: Ficou bem próximo do que eu queria, mas a imagem não ficou centralizada :/ Vou postar o código que funcionou pra mim, mas obrigada mesmo assim

Answer (score 2):

A maneira que encontrei foi centralizar a imagem dentro de um div retangular, colocar dentro de um div quadrado, puxar para esquerda a metade da sobra, e por fim ocultar o overflow e arredondar o div pai de todos:

```css
.posts .posts-item img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  background-position: center center;
}
figure img {
  width: auto;
  height: 12rem;
}
.round-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 12rem;
  height: 12rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.c {
  position: relative;
  width: 24rem;
  left: -6rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="posts-item">
  <div class="title">Conheça a lista dos melhores cafés</div>
  <figure>
    <div class="round-container">
      <div class="c">
        <img src="http://vidafit.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/cafe-coracao-776x517.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, onsectetur dispiscing</figcaption>
  </figure>
</a>
```

Comment: Perfeito! Hahaha Era exatamente assim que eu precisava! Eu vou postar meu código aqui, que ficou um pouco mais otimizado (16 linhas). Eu usei o transform, que praticamente deu o mesmo resultado. Obrigada ;)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a propriedade [clip-path](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clip/), mas veja que ela tem um suporte [não tão bom](http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path).

```css
img {
  width: 350px;
  height: 300px;
}

.circle {
  clip-path: circle(150px at center);
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(150px at center);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://vidafit.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/cafe-coracao-776x517.jpg" alt="" class="circle">
```

Perceba que estou prefixando a propriedade, o que é mais um sinal de como ela não é assim tão adotada. Você deve ajustar, obviamente, as dimensões da imagem e do *clipping* para as suas necessidades.

[Aqui](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) tem um gerador de *clips* bem bacana, com diversos formatos.

Comment: O colega negativador poderia explicar exatamente o que tem de errado com a minha resposta. Quem sabe assim posso melhorá-la para o agrado de todos.

Comment: Eu estava procurando diversos clips, já que o meu transform não estava mais funcionando, mas eu consegui arrumar agora! Vou postar a resposta em breve. Obrigada ;)